# Why doesn't VB.Net type inference work in class fields?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, variables, field, type-inference

If I were to type the following into a method body:

```
Dim myInt = 1
```

the Visual Studio IDE (and therefore, I am guessing, the compiler) infers the type of `myInt` to be `Integer`.

**EDIT**

Apparently using a literal was a bad choice here, since I've become embroiled in a lengthy debate that has nothing to do with the question. If you take issue with the fact that the expression `1` might be interpreted as an instance of different numeric types, pretend I had written:

```
Dim myInstance = New MyClass()
```

**END EDIT**

However, when I put a field declaration with the exact same code at the top of a *class*, the type of `myList` is not inferred:

```
Public Class Foo
    Dim myInt = 1
End Class
```

On mouseover, it mentions the absence of an As clause, and says a type of Object has been assumed. I cannot pass `myInt` as an argument to a function or sub that expects an Integer argument, without explicitly adding an As clause or casting to Integer.

Is there a discrepancy between how the IDE and compiler deal with type inference? If, on the other hand, the compiler can't infer type in this situation either, why the discrepancy between method variables and class fields?

Comment: The right question is why does the compiler let you write a line like that! :-) IMHO you should run with Option Strict On and standardize on explicit type declarations.

Comment: My guess is that variables declared at class level can be anything (generic Object, a Collection, a function pointer, primitive type, etc) so it makes the broadest possible assumption (Object).  But within a method the options are reduced so the types can be narrowed.  But As Marcello stated, better to shoot for strong typing whenever possible.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani I'm not sure what is unsafe about this, especially when all necessary type information is present. If I were to explicitly coerce the type of the value I am assigning to `myInt` to an integer, i.e. `Dim myInt = 1I`, the results do not change.

Comment: Let me ask you one question: does the ASCII symbol 1 represent a Float, Double or Int if you interpret it as a number ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani Let me ask you this question: can the 2 character expression `1I` ever represent more than one divergent type?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani `1I` can only be an instance of an Integer or an ancestor type thereof. There is no ambiguity here.

Comment: Let's forget you wrote Dim myInt = 1 in the first place. It looks to me like by writing 1I you're basically spoon-feeding the type inference system. At that point, you're just moving the "burden" of declaring the variable type from the actual declaration to the initialization data. Looks like a very bad coding practice to me.

Comment: Ok 1I is unambiguous. But then what do you gain by going from Dim a as Integer = 1 to Dim a = 1I and making the compiler implicitly add "as Integer" to that ?

Comment: Another aspect of this, is the philosophy behind Basic.  Making explicit declarations also has the advantage of making the code much more readable and understandable, especially if several years go by  until you look at the code again.  As long as the compiler can understand what you write, it doesn't really care if it's more readable.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani You're missing the point of the question. This isn't about strong typing best practices. The question is why the compiler is OK with inferring type in a method body when there is no ambiguity (regardless of whether you have removed ambiguity by "spoon feeding" it) but not OK with doing the same in a class field? Are there any special circumstances surrounding class fields that I am not aware of?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani ***"But then what do you gain by going from Dim a as Integer = 1 to Dim a = 1I and making the compiler implicitly add "as Integer" to that ?"*** That's the problem. The compiler (or at least the IDE) *is* implictly adding the "As Integer" you speak of in some places, but refusing to do so in others.

Comment: Actually in your original question there is ambiguity.  The compiler is just interpreting the data differently in different situations.  If there was no ambiguity then the compiler would interpret it the same way.

Comment: @tinstaafl If there is no ambiguity the problem remains. You can try this yourself if you have a copy of VS. A field in a class declaration that reads `Dim myInt = 1I` still registers as Object. There is no such problem in a method body.

Comment: Looks like "class fields do not support type inferencing"

stackoverflow.com/questions/339397/vb-net-and-type-inference-using-dim

Comment: Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163345.aspx (See figure 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've found is that way on purpose.   here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384937%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) expalanation.

> Local type inference applies at procedure level. It cannot be used to
>   declare variables at module level (within a class, structure, module,
>   or interface but not within a procedure or block). If num2 in the
>   previous example were a field of a class instead of a local variable
>   in a procedure, the declaration would cause an error with Option
>   Strict on, and would classify num2 as an Object with Option Strict
>   off. Similarly, local type inference does not apply to procedure level
>   variables declared as Static.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up. It still doesn't answer the "why", but I'll settle for this.